# Using Hibernate console in a Grails app using Intellij IDEA

Tags: hibernate, grails

I am trying to get Hibernate console in a Grails application. Since Grails use Hibernate under the hood, I believe this should be possible but do not know how to do it.

Grails version: 3.1.4

Answer (score 0):

No, but you can vote for the feature request here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-48621